# How strong can a glacial icequake get?

Tags: seismology, glaciology, antarctic, ice-sheets

While researching Antarctic geology, I came across the term 'icequake' in the abstract to the article [Seismicity within a propagating ice shelf rift: The relationship between icequake locations and ice shelf structure](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2013JF002849/abstract) (Heeszel et al. 2014).

These events are also known as [cryoseisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryoseism) - in reference to glaciers, the Wikipedia article describes a cryoseism as:

> a non-tectonic seismic event caused by sudden glacial movements. This movement has been attributed to a veneer of water which may pool underneath a glacier sourced from surface ice melt. Hydraulic pressure of the liquid can act as a lubricant, allowing the glacier to suddenly shift position. This type of cryoseism can be very brief, or may last for several minutes.

and describe them as being able to

> have an intensity of up to VI on the Modified Mercalli Scale

**Is there a limit to how high glacial icequake magnitudes (Richter Scale) can be?**

Comment: [This link](http://wisblawg.law.wisc.edu/2008/02/ice-quake-shakes-uw-madison-campus/) records an icequake of 3,8 Richter - but that wasn't the strongest one in the world, just in the Madison's lakes region. I would expect the strongest ones to occur in Antarctica and avoid measurement.

Answer (score 4):

One way to estimate the upper limit of the magnitude is through observations and measurements.  According to the article [Seismic Wave Interactions Between
the Atmosphere - Ocean - Cryosphere
System and the Geosphere in Polar Regions](http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs-wm/26243.pdf), a couple of difficulties with determining how large ice-quakes can get, asides from the regions not monitored, are due to the sources of the recorded motion and delineating cryoseismic and tectonic observations. From the article:

> Such cryoseismic sources include the movements of ice sheets, sea-ice,
>   oceanic tide-cracks, oceanic gravity waves, icebergs and the calving fronts of ice caps. **At
>   times, it can be hard to distinguish between the waveforms generated by local tectonic
>   earthquakes and those of ice-related phenomena.**

However, in the Scientific American article [Long-Overlooked "Ice Quakes" Data Provides Insights into Calving Glaciers](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/long-overlooked-ice-quakes-data-provides-insights-into-calving-glaciers/), they can be identified by their location and unique waveforms identified relatively recently.

According to the first article, unlike tectonic events, cryoseismic (= ice-quake) events are seasonal and heavily climate-dependent, with the article detailing that observations have shown that in polar regions

> microseism amplitude is attenuated during local winter for both primary and
>   secondary microseisms

Observations of body-wave magnitudes (Mb) between 1987-2007 in an Antarctic station were up to 6.5-7.0

A recent observation are the related 'glacial quakes', which generated log period surface waves (greater than 25s) which, according to the article, is

> equivalent in strength to those radiated by
>   standard magnitude five earthquakes, and were observable worldwide. The glacial
>   earthquakes radiated little high-frequency energy, which explains why they were not
>   detected or located by traditional earthquake-monitoring systems. These events are two
>   magnitude units larger than previously reported seismic phenomena associated with
>   glaciers, a size difference corresponding to a factor of 1,000 in a seismic moment.

Similar observations have been made in the Greenland ice sheet.

NOAA has some sample cryoseismic traces on their PMEL Acoustics page [Icequakes](http://www.pmel.noaa.gov/acoustics/sounds/bloop.html).

Answer (score 0):

This isnt an answer, but may point you in the right direction

http://eost.u-strasbg.fr/semipgs/pres_Walter_04_03_08.pdf

Comment: Could you provide a summary of the relevant points in the document in addition to the link?

Comment: @aretxabaleta I could sure, but it would be a rough summary at best as it does contain a lot of equations and its a bit out of my realm of expertise. If it would be helpful I can take a stab though.